# How do I reduce complexity of my swap algorithm to sort 5 numbers?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

I am practicing to manually sort 5 numbers by comparing them with each other I have to loop it with n^2 times but I want to reduce it.

```
a1 = 100
a2 = 90
a3 = 45
a4 = 8
a5 = 0
i = 0
while i < 25:
    if a1 > a2:
        tmp = a1
        a1 = a2
        a2 = tmp
    elif a1 > a3:
        tmp = a1
        a1 = a3
        a3 = tmp
    elif a1 > a4:
        tmp = a1
        a1 = a4
        a4 = tmp
    elif a1 > a5:
        tmp = a1
        a1 = a5
        a5 = tmp
    elif a2 > a3:
        tmp = a2
        a2 = a3
        a3 = tmp
    elif a2 > a4:
        tmp = a2
        a2 = a4
        a4 = tmp
    elif a2 > a5:
        tmp = a2
        a2 = a5
        a5 = tmp
    elif a3 > a4:
        tmp = a3
        a3 = a4
        a4 = tmp
    elif a3 > a5:
        tmp = a3
        a3 = a5
        a5 = tmp
    elif a4 > a5:
        tmp = a4
        a4 = a5
        a5 = tmp
    i = i + 1
print(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
```

The code is able to sort the numbers but as you can see loop of i runs until 25 times to sort all the numbers.

Comment: look into other sort algorithms, like heapsort, quicksort ...

Comment: I was just wondering if this code can be more optimal or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, this algorithm isn't very good - but you could make the code better (which, as I understand it is what you ask for).

instead of using a temp var for the swap, you can do

```
a1, a2 = a2, a1
```

doing away with the three lines.

also instead of

```
i = 0
while i < 25
    ...
    i += 1
```

you can use

```
for i in range(25):
    ...
```

which is more elegant.

Comment: I rarely use python, so I wasn't aware of this. I've deleted that comment and will delete this on later fo avoid unneeded comments.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an algorithm which has a time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

You need to use some faster algorithms like `Merge sort` or `Quick sort`. But for previously sorted data `Quick sort` will give a bad performance, that's why I suggest using `Merge sort` here.

Also, you may use the `Count sort` algorithm, but sometimes it is not a good solution.

So, learn the [Merge sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/) algorithm and use it to get `O(nlogn)` time complexity!

Answer (score 0):

`Merge Sort` is ideal for general cases, as the order is `nlogn` for the best, average and worst cases. But I suggest otherwise, because the `Merge Sort` would not be any better than some simple `O(n^2)` for mere 5 items to sort.

If you are looking for an efficient way to sort these 5 numbers in shortest steps possible, then you might find this answer helpful. Here, the 5 numbers are sorted with just 7 steps (worst case). Whereas, even the `Merge Sort` procedure takes at least 8 steps (forget the complex code for the Merge Sort).

> Sort array of 5 integers with a max of 7 compares (https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10969)

Answer (score 0):

> I was just wondering if this code can be more optimal ...

The code is a bubble sort. The code only needs to loop 4 times, not 25 times. The code moves the largest element to a5 on the first loop, then the next largest to a4 on the second loop, then a3 on third loop, and a2 on fourth loop, leaving the smallest in a1. Unfolding the loop for bubble sort, it takes 10 compare and swap operations:

```
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
if a2 > a3: a2,a3 = a3,a2
if a3 > a4: a3,a4 = a4,a3
if a4 > a5: a4,a5 = a5,a4
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
if a2 > a3: a2,a3 = a3,a2
if a3 > a4: a3,a4 = a4,a3
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
if a2 > a3: a2,a3 = a3,a2
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
```

---

This can be reduced to 9 compare and swap operations using one of 180 possible [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) for 5 elements. Processor optimization could do some of the compares and swaps in parallel if the operations are independent (don't involve the same variables):

```
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
if a3 > a4: a3,a4 = a3,a4
if a1 > a3: a1,a3 = a3,a1
if a2 > a5: a2,a5 = a5,a2
if a1 > a2: a1,a2 = a2,a1
if a3 > a4: a3,a4 = a3,a4
if a2 > a3: a2,a3 = a3,a2
if a4 > a5: a4,a5 = a4,a5
if a3 > a4: a3,a4 = a3,a4
```

---

Similar to the link in Sayooj Samuel's answer, using a combination of swaps and insertions, the number of compares can be reduced from 9 to 7, but it's still a maximum of 18 assignments that would be swaps or moves in other programming languages, the else statements would result in unconditional jumps on most processors, and there are more sequence dependencies, so this may be slower than sorting network.

```
if a1 > a2:      a1,a2       = a2,a1
if a3 > a4:      a3,a4       = a4,a3
if a1 > a3:      a1,a2,a3,a4 = a3,a4,a1,a2
if a3 > a5:
    if a1 > a5:  a1,a3,a4,a5 = a5,a1,a3,a4
    else:        a3,a4,a5    = a5,a3,a4
else:
    if a4 > a5:  a4,a5 = a5,a4
if a2 > a4:
    if a2 > a5:  a2,a3,a4,a5 = a3,a4,a5,a2
    else:        a2,a3,a4,a5 = a3,a4,a2,a5
else:
    if a2 > a3:  a2,a3       = a3,a2
```